# Saving directory name and folder size as 2d array

Tags: php, html

I use this code to print the subfolders name and size in a HTML table, what I want to do is save this table as a 2d array so it can be sorted by folder size (since right now is sorted by alphabetical name order)

```
<?php

$directory = "F:/directory";

echo "<table>";
$depth = 0;
$count = 0;

$ritit = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS), RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);
$r = array();
foreach ( $ritit as $splFileInfo ) {
    $count +=1;
    if ($ritit->getDepth() === $depth && $splFileInfo->isDir()) {
        echo "<tr><td>".stripslashes($splFileInfo)."</td>";
        echo "<td>".getSize($splFileInfo)."</td></tr>";
    }
}
echo "</table>";
function getSize($dir, $precision = 2) {
    $ritit = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS));
    $bytes = 0;
    foreach ( $ritit as $v ) {
        $bytes += $v->getSize();
    }
    $bytes = max($bytes, 0);
    return round($bytes, $precision) . ' ';
}
?>
```

This is the HTML with the folder name on the left and the folder size on the right
[image: W]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the filename as the key and the filesize as the value in $r 2D-array. Use the sort function to the sort the array using value.

Here is the link to sort the array: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_sort.asp

```
<?php

$directory = "F:/directory";

echo "<table>";
$depth = 0;
$count = 0;

$ritit = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS), RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);
$r = array();
foreach ( $ritit as $splFileInfo ) {
    $count +=1;
    if ($ritit->getDepth() === $depth && $splFileInfo->isDir()) {
        // echo "<tr><td>".stripslashes($splFileInfo)."</td>";
        // echo "<td>".getSize($splFileInfo)."</td></tr>";
        $r[stripslashes($splFileInfo)] = getSize($splFileInfo);
    }
}

// sort the associative array using the value.
asort($r);

foreach($r as $key => $value) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$key."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$value."</td></tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
function getSize($dir, $precision = 2) {
    $ritit = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS));
    $bytes = 0;
    foreach ( $ritit as $v ) {
        $bytes += $v->getSize();
    }
    $bytes = max($bytes, 0);
    return round($bytes, $precision) . ' ';
}
?>
```